# SSL-certificate; Green lock is sometimes not displaying

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have a website that has an SSL-certificate. When I enter the homepage everything is correct and a green lock is displayed in the url, see my website [here](https://www.feelhome.se/).

The issue is that this lock is not being displayed on some pages. [Here is an image of it.](https://s32.postimg.org/6sogr7f9x/stack.jpg)

How can I assure that the green lock is being displayed on ALL pages on the website?

I have noticed that when I insert the website that doesn't have the green look at first the look appears while the website is loading and after finished loading it disappears.

EDIT 1, the code below is used to re-write all URLS with www to "https://". This one I have implemented into my .htacess-file.

```
RewriteEngine On

# If not using www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

# If using www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: it's mostly likely because you have mixed content. make sure all the urls on the page uses https:// protocol not http://

Comment: And to find out more where this mixed content comes from take a look at the browsers console.

Comment: @unixmiah All URL use https:// when I look at them. What do you mean by "mixed contant", the "https://"? How can I "assure" all the urls on the pages usses https://, maybe in the .htacess file?

Comment: @Rob Lundgren you have about 46 links that start with http:// on your page url: https://www.feelhome.se/topplistan/

Comment: @SteffenUllrich where can I find the browser console?

Comment: @unixmiah In OP you can observe the code I have added inside of my .htacess file to re-write the URLs of the website. Is that not correct? You found 46 links, how can I fix these?

Comment: @RobinLundgren: how about [just searching the web](https://www.google.com/search?q=browser+console) or looking through the menus? Where exactly this is depends on the browser but usually it is within something like developer tools which every web developer should use.

Comment: @unixmiah One thing that I find strange is that if I enter the website from a friends MAC-computer then all pages works fine except for the checkout one. 

But on my computers there are alot of pages not displaying the green lock.

Comment: @unixmiah How can I fix the 46 links that doesn't have the correct URL? I tried the "velvet blues update URLs" for wordpress, but it gives me an error message: https://s31.postimg.org/qbz2npmxn/image.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by using this plugin https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/wordpress-https

Can anyone sudgest me how to solve my problem without using the plugin maybe? Somehow some URLs are not being updated.... any idea on how to do it manually instead of using plugin?

Answer (score 0):

My best guess would be that your page contains some non-https content.

Add Following meta value to your header. Basically it will force non HTTPS to use HTTPS secure connection url.

If you want to allow the Mixed Content request, then add the below tag into  tag.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
```

If you want to block then add the below tag into the  tag

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="block-all-mixed-content">
```